# Given a large array of tuples, how to groupby the first element of each tuple in order to sum the last element of each tuple without Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, tuples, aggregation, python-itertools, itertools-groupby

I have a large list of tuples where each tuple contains 9 string elements:

```
pdf_results = [
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/18/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/18/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/19/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/19/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/20/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/20/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/21/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/21/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/23/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/24/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
("Kohl's - Dallas", '-', "Kohl's Cafe", '03/24/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', '-', 'Patient Trayline ', '03/18/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', '-', 'Patient Trayline ', '03/18/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5'),
('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', '-', 'Patient Trayline ', '03/19/22', 'RC', '8', '0', '16', '8'),
('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', '-', 'Patient Trayline ', '03/19/22', 'SMI', '5', '0', '10', '5')
]
```

Without using a Pandas dataframe, how best to group by the first element of each tuple in order to sum the last element of each tuple. Output should look like this:

```
desired_output = [
("Kohl's - Dallas", 70),
("Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center", 26)
]
```

I've tried using `itertools.groupby` which seems to be the most appropriate solution; however, getting stuck on properly iterating, indexing, and summing the last element of each tuple without running into one of the following obstacles:

1. The last element of each tuple is of type `string` and upon converting to `int` prevents iteration as `TypeError: 'int' object not iterable`
2. `ValueError` is raised where `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'`

Attempt:

```
from itertools import groupby

def getSiteName(siteChunk):
    return siteChunk[0]

siteNameGroup = groupby(pdf_results, getSiteName)

for key, group in siteNameGroup:
    print(key) # 1st element of tuple as desired
    for pdf_results in group:
        # Raises TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
        print(sum(pdf_results[8]))
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is sorted by the first element, you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby 

for k,v in groupby(pdf_results, key=lambda t: t[0]):
    print(k, sum(int(x[-1]) for x in v))
```

Prints:

```
Kohl's - Dallas 70
Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center 26
```

If the order is not sorted, just use a `dict` to total the elements keyed by the the first entry of the tuple:

```
res={}

for t in pdf_results:
    res[t[0]]=res.get(t[0],0)+int(t[-1])

>>> res
{"Kohl's - Dallas": 70, 'Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center': 26}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simple `for` loop on a empty dictionary?

```py
resultDict = {}
for value in pdf_results:
  if value[0] not in resultDict:
    resultDict[value[0]] = 0
  resultDict[value[0]] += float(value[len(value)-1])
print(resultDict)
```

##### Output

```
{"Kohl's - Dallas": 70.0,
'Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center': 26.0}
```

If a dictionary is not what you want and you are insisting on having a tuple instead, you can use:

```py
list(resultDict.items())
```

##### Output

```
[("Kohl's - Dallas", 70.0), ('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', 26.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just change your

```
for pdf_results in group:
    print(sum(pdf_results[8]))
```

to:

```
print(sum(int(pdf_results[8])
          for pdf_results in group))
```

(Though I'd also rename to `pdf_result`, singular.)

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(int)

for item in pdf_results:
    output[item[0]] += int(item[-1])

print(list(output.items()))
```

### Output

```
[("Kohl's - Dallas", 70), ('Bronx-Lebanon Hospital Center', 26)]
```